# How to set form action to PHP file and new HTML page?

Tags: php, html

I'm just starting to learn PHP and built a simple pizza ordering site to take orders and submit it to my database. I want the order form to not only to POST the customer's order details, but also redirect to a new HTML page that takes customer's information. Here's what I tried.

```
<form action="http://localhost/pizza/pizzaform.html" action="pizza.php" method="post">
```

Unfortunately, only the first form action seems to work. How is it possible to execute both of these?I have also pasted my `pizza.php` code below .

PHP

```
<?php

require("pizzacnn.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM `customers`";
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM `inventory`";

if ($query_run = (mysqli_query($cnn,$query))){

echo "tables found";

$sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name,address,phone_number, money,feedback) VALUES ('{$_POST['name']}','{$_POST['address']}','{$_POST['phone']}','{$_POST['money']}','{$_POST['feedback']}')";

}

else if ($query2_run = (mysqli_query($cnn,$query2)){

$sql = "INSERT INTO inventory (toppings,number) VALUES ('{$_POST['topping']},'{$_POST['number']}')";

}

if ($cnn->query($sql)===TRUE){echo "record created succcessfully";}
else {
echo "Error: ".$sql."<br>".$cnn->error;
}

?>
```

Comment: Redirect can be done with `header` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like this

```
<form action="pizzaorder.php" method="post">
```

After the Oder insert into your database

```
 $success = $cnn->query($sql);
 if ($success) {
   header("Location:thankyou.php"); /* Redirect browser to thankyou*/
 } else {
   echo "Whoops! Looks like something went wrong";
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use one action, and redirect the user after the sql is done.

From the php docs

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```